# Get specific data from table with xPath

Tags: xml, xpath, html-table, xpath-2.0

I've this table with source code [HERE](http://pastebin.com/f86dWtnq):

[image]

I want to get all rows, wich I can do using:

[image]

The expected final output using `string-join($doc//*[@id='salaries']/tbody/tr/normalize-space(.), '&#xA;')` is:

```
1985-86 Los Angeles Lakers NBA $2,030,000
1987-88 Los Angeles Lakers NBA $2,000,000
1988-89 Los Angeles Lakers NBA $3,000,000
```

My question is, how to remove the third column (named NBA in this example) from the final output to get this:

```
1985-86 Los Angeles Lakers $2,030,000
1987-88 Los Angeles Lakers $2,000,000
1988-89 Los Angeles Lakers $3,000,000
```

ps: I'm not sure that column is always in that place, but the anchor contains 'league' in it `a[contains(@href, 'league')]`

Comment: Rather than the picture, can you show the source?

Comment: @choroba, yup, I forgot it xD ... post updated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This XPath 2.0 expression**:

```
  for $i in 1 to count(/tbody/tr),
      $r in /tbody/tr[$i],
      $s in string-join($r/td[not(position() eq 3)]/normalize-space(.), ' ')
   return
     concat($s, '&#xA;')
```

**when evaluated on the provided XML document**:

```
<tbody>
<tr class="" data-row="0">
   <td align="left">1985-86</td>
   <td align="left"><a href="/teams/LAL/1986.html">Los Angeles Lakers</a></td>
   <td align="left"><a href="/leagues/NBA_1986.html">NBA</a></td>
   <td align="right" csk="2030000">$2,030,000</td>
</tr>
<tr class="" data-row="1">
   <td align="left">1987-88</td>
   <td align="left"><a href="/teams/LAL/1988.html">Los Angeles Lakers</a></td>
   <td align="left"><a href="/leagues/NBA_1988.html">NBA</a></td>
   <td align="right" csk="2000000">$2,000,000</td>
</tr>
<tr class="" data-row="2">
   <td align="left">1988-89</td>
   <td align="left"><a href="/teams/LAL/1989.html">Los Angeles Lakers</a></td>
   <td align="left"><a href="/leagues/NBA_1989.html">NBA</a></td>
   <td align="right" csk="3000000">$3,000,000</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
 1985-86 Los Angeles Lakers $2,030,000
 1987-88 Los Angeles Lakers $2,000,000
 1988-89 Los Angeles Lakers $3,000,000
```

**If the position of the column to be excluded isn't guaranteed to be fixed, use**:

```
  for $i in 1 to count(/tbody/tr),
      $r in /tbody/tr[$i],
      $s in string-join($r/td[not(starts-with(a/@href,'/leagues'))]
                              /normalize-space(.), ' ')
   return
     concat($s, '&#xA;')
```

Comment: Awsome, I've never seen a for like this :o ... just perfect as usual :)

Comment: @Enissay: You are welcome. I am curious - what is your platform? What specific XPath 2.0 processor are you using and with what host language?

Comment: Well, As I said in my previous questions, I'm using this in Web-Harvest's scripts... Here's some examples: http://web-harvest.sourceforge.net/samples.php... I hope this answers your question :)

Comment: To sum up, it uses xml syntax, xPath, xQuery, and if needed, another scripting language [Javascript, Beanshell/Java or Groovy]...

Comment: @Enissay, Thanks, I'll look at it -- this seems to be a rather comprehensive tool.

Answer (score 2):

To exlude the third column, use

```
tbody/tr/td[position()!=3]
```

To exlude the links containing `league`, you can use

```
tbody/tr/td[not(contains(a/@href,'league'))]
```

Comment: Well, I already tried that, but I couldn't manage to get the final output above :/